# Optimize and configure Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

Today, suddenly my database is running very slowly. Looking at the "Status" tab in PHPMyAdmin I realize that the following parameters are marked in red:

```
Slow_queries    146         
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    24.9 k
Innodb_row_lock_waits   2
Handler_read_rnd    752.9 M
Handler_read_rnd_next   3.8 G
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    690.3 k
Created_tmp_disk_tables     1.3 M
Select_full_join    108.7 k
Opened_tables   21.2 k
Table_locks_waited  5
```

The indices of some tables are really high and have more than 1 million rows.
The identifier id of users displayed in the "processlist" is very high (341139); Prior maximum was around 1000.

There are multiple databases with different engines. The heavier have Innodb, MyISAM others. 
My current setup is the following:

```
max_connections = 400
query_cache_size = 128M
table_cache=2048
tmp_table_size = 1G
thread_cache_size=286
connect_timeout = 100
interactive_timeout = 100
wait_timeout = 500
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
open_files_limit = 8192
max_allowed_packet = 16000M
join_buffer_size = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 1G
key_cache_block_size = 1024
max_sort_length = 1024
key_cache_division_limit = 100
skip-partition
//MY ISAM
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=2G
key_buffer_size=64M
read_buffer_size=256M
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=2G
//INNO DB
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_thread_concurrency=17
```

The server on which it is installed has the following features:

```
Server Rack Dell R410
CPU: Intel Xeon Quad L5609 4x core 1.86
RAM: 16 GB
HardDisk: 2 x 1 TB SATA a 7200 rpm
OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard 64 Bit
Connectivity: 100 Mbit/s
```

On the server, in addition to the database, there is an executable program that runs continuously (working on the database) and it consumes about 20% of the CPU.

Days ago I tried to optimize the database with the tool MySQLTuner but I think this has worsened the situation.
The last restart of the database dates back to 4 days ago.

What can I do to fix and to better optimize the speed of the database?

Comment: No one in the world can help me? :(

Comment: Can you define what you mean by your "database is running very slowly" please? Does the problem only occur when executing certain queries / certain page requests or with every query? When you execute mysqltuner, what output do you get?